# JacksonMapper to deserialize null value

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am going to deserialize Json null value to Java Object empty string

I am able to make my custom deserializer, but when the Json value is null, it did not go into the deserializer.

How should I deserialize it?

Thanks in advance!

```
public class CustomStringDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<String> {
@Override
public String deserialize(JsonParser jsonparser, DeserializationContext deserializationcontext) throws IOException,
        JsonProcessingException {

    String str = jsonparser.getText();

    try {
        return (str == null) ? "" : str;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

}
```

}

```
   public CustomObjectMapper() {
        SimpleModule _module = new SimpleModule("Module", new Version(1, 9, 10, "FINAL"));
        _module.addDeserializer(String.class, new CustomStringDeserializer());
}
```

**Thanks @nutlike**

I do this by

```
    @Override
public String getNullValue() {
    return "";
}
```

Comment: Tell me why question voted down, so I can improve next time.

Comment: Nobody can answer your question if you don't provide some code and/or configuration related to the problem.

Comment: @Bart, Thanks for commenting, I add back the code now.

Comment: Maybe it would be sufficient to overwrite the method [getNullValue()](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.1.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonDeserializer.html#getNullValue%28%29)?

Comment: @nutlike You are right!
I just figure out this too!

Comment: Added an answer so you may mark your question as solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it would be sufficient to overwrite the method [getNullValue()](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.1.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonDeserializer.html#getNullValue%28%29)?

```
public class CustomStringDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<String> {

@Override
public String deserialize(JsonParser jsonparser,
        DeserializationContext deserializationcontext) throws IOException,
        JsonProcessingException {

    return jsonparser.getText();

}

@Override
public String getNullValue() {
    return "";
}

}
```

Comment: getNullValue is deprecated by the way